# Revoked cert not showing revoked in Chrome 64.0.3282.186

Tags: chrome, certificate-revocation

As far as I can tell (ssllabs.com / ssldecoder.org) the certificate for www.sarahah.com has been revoked:

```
Serial  C1:18:2F:1A:91:A9:0E:03

CRL - Revoked on CRL: http://crl.godaddy.com/gdig2s1-792.crl
Revocation date: Mar 1 18:19:00 2018 GMT

OCSP    - REVOKED: http://ocsp.godaddy.com/
Revocation Time: Mar 1 18:19:00 2018 GMT
Revocation Reason: cessationOfOperation
```

This shows as `SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE` in Firefox 58.0.2, as it should.

However Chrome 64 seems to be perfectly happy with it! Any idea what's going on?

Obviously the hostname resolves to multiple IPs, but behaviour seems consistent in Firefox and Chrome with multiple refreshes.

[image: Chrome 64 screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Firefox uses OCSP to check for revocation Google Chrome uses [CRLsets](https://dev.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/crlsets) which include only revocations which are considered to be important by the project - which sadly does not include all revoked certificates. And the site you have visited does not seem to be important enough to be included in the CRLsets.

For a deeper discussion about this problem see [An Evaluation of the Effectiveness
of Chrome's CRLSets (2014)](https://www.grc.com/revocation/crlsets.htm), [Revocation checking and Chrome's CRL (2012)](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/02/05/crlsets.html) or [SSL certificate revocation and how it is broken in practice (2018)](https://medium.com/@alexeysamoshkin/how-ssl-certificate-revocation-is-broken-in-practice-af3b63b9cb3).

Comment: Interesting. Not that I care about the site, but the Alexa rank is 3,465, and 107th in Egypt for some reason.
But the docs say "Only entries that have no reason code, or one of the following reason codes are included in the CRLSet: Unspecified, KeyCompromise, CACompromise or AACompromise."
So the explicit reason above would exclude this revocation.